# In drupal how can I theme 2 blocks within the same region differently?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

How can I theme different blocks present within the same region differently. For instance say there are 3 blocks in the right sidebar. I want to set the background of the top block red, background of middle block yellow and that of the bottom block blue then how should I do it.

Any tips or pointers would be appreciated . (I would like to mention here that I am aware of the Block theme module yet would want to know if this can be achieved using dynamic template suggestions)
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will depend a little on your theme or base theme. Most all of them add a unique ID to the div around the blocks such as *block-block-15* that you can then style with your CSS. Other themes, such as the Zen base theme, add even more helpful classes such as *region-even*, *region-count-2*, or *count-3*.

Comment: Yup the template suggestion (block-block-delta.tpl.php) is what I was actually looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

excuse my english. I m not very good at it.

you can theme each block differently.
If you inspect the block using fire bug you can get the id of that block.
you can suggest the template based on that id.
so find the main block temp file which is block.tpl.
copy the content of the block.tpl to another file and save it as id_of_the_block.tpl.
then you can change the theme of the block you want by modifying in new template file.

you it will help you